# RabbitMQ CPU Usage Spikes

Tags: kubernetes, cpu-usage, rabbitmq, k3s

I've installed RabbitMQ on kubernetes(k3s) on ARM (Oracle OCI Ampere A1) using the community docker image.

I'm seeing very regular periodic CPU usage spikes (two series of spikes, both with a period of 60 seconds and offset by about 20 or so seconds). Is this normal? Is there something I can do to reduce these?

[image: Netdata CPU Utilization for the RabbitMQ Namespace]

This is an entirely empty installation of RabbitMQ, I haven't even tried to connect to it. I'm concerned that these CPU usage spikes might get worse when there are messages actually flowing through rabbitmq.

The configuration I'm using is:

```
enabled_plugins: |
  [rabbitmq_peer_discovery_k8s, rabbitmq_management, rabbitmq_prometheus].
rabbitmq.conf: |
  cluster_formation.peer_discovery_backend = k8s
  cluster_formation.k8s.host = kubernetes.default.svc.devcluster.oci.domain
  cluster_formation.k8s.address_type = hostname
  cluster_formation.k8s.service_name = rabbitmq-internode-svc
  queue_master_locator=min-masters
```

I want to be able to scale it up later, but presently I have only one RabbitMQ pod.

I also have some probes configured from k3s with a 60s period, could these be the cause of this CPU usage? If I remember correctly (I had written the k3s service many months ago now), these were based on RabbitMQ recommendations for k8s deployments.

```
  livenessProbe:
      exec:
        command: ["rabbitmq-diagnostics", "status"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 60
      periodSeconds: 60
      timeoutSeconds: 15
  readinessProbe:
      exec:
        command: ["rabbitmq-diagnostics", "ping"]
      initialDelaySeconds: 20
      periodSeconds: 60
      timeoutSeconds: 10
```